# Is it necessary to separate mapWebRoutes()

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.6.x

I'm practicing, trying to separate frontend and admin login. I did it years ago. Now I'm back to PHP programing. I'm trying to know how I did. Then I'll do it on Laravel 9. I used different tables. It seems to be working fine. users table for admin, members table for frontend.

I use the same `mapWebRoutes()` in `RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
}
```

I see some posts separate functions,
`mapWebRoutes()` and `mapAdminRoutes()`

Is it necessary to separate functions?

Comment: Nope it isn't necessary, however, some would argue it provides a clean seperation of responsibility.

Comment: @Peppermintology Thank you. Could you please answer this question with what you said, and I'll mark as answered.